# How to Fix PayPal IPN Validation Error in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, paypal, e-commerce

> Validation error: PayPal IPN response from a different email address (email@gmail.com). Order status changed from Pending payment to On hold.

Wordpress ecommerce Website paypal IPN not working

Tried solutions

1. Checking about the email is set to primary paypal email.
2. Checking the IP List whitelist for Paypal ipn,

And everything is fine, but then too i get this error.

Comment: Please share code to demonstrate the steps you take and what line(s) cause the error.

Answer (score 1):

Please go to this URL and take note of the email addresses:

https://www.paypal.com/businessprofile/settings/

The Receiver email in WooCommerce > Settings > Payments > PayPal will need to be the primary email listed on that page. The PayPal email can be any of the rest of the emails from the page at PayPal.

Side note, it is not good to post emails in threads, as you can wind up on mailing lists. I requested an admin to remove your emails as soon as I saw them.

Source after using Google for one minute: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/validation-error-paypal-ipn-response-from-a-different-email-address-2/